# install_bitbucket in devtools: case-sensitive?

Tags: r, devtools

```
library(devtools)
install_bitbucket("readlicor","remkoduursma")
```

works fine! However:

```
install_bitbucket("GasExchangeR","remkoduursma")
```

does not, it appears to be looking for:

```
bitbucket.org/remkoduursma/GasExchangeR/get/master.zip
```

but that page does not exist, instead:

```
bitbucket.org/remkoduursma/gasexchanger/get/master.zip
```

does exist.

Is there a workaround (besides renaming all my packages to lower case names), or is this a bug?

thanks
remko

Answer (score 2):

While you wait for this to be fixed in `devtools`,  you could redefine the function to change `repo` to all lower case, if this is a `bitbucket` convention.

```
install_bitbucket <- function (repo, username, ref = "master", branch = NULL, ...) {
  if (!is.null(branch)) {
    warning("'branch' is deprecated. In the future, please use 'ref' instead.")
    ref <- branch
  }

  repo <- tolower(repo)
  message("Installing bitbucket repo(s) ", paste(repo, ref, 
                                                 sep = "/", collapse = ", "), " from ", paste(username, 
                                                                                              collapse = ", "))
  url <- paste("https://bitbucket.org/", username, "/", repo, 
               "/get/", ref, ".zip", sep = "")
  install_url(url, paste(ref, ".zip", sep = ""), ...)
}
```

I have sent a [pull request](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/pull/175) to `devtools` to make this change.

Comment: What is the point unless he can send a pull request to `devtools`?

Comment: I just sent the pull request. I've voted to close the question as too localized